# How to block phone call in android without displaying the call?

Tags: android, telephony

In Android I can implement phone blocker using telephony API by listening to phone state, but it shows a window with phone number and decline and accept buttons. For some reason I don't want this window.

In my test I used Device Monitor to call the simulated Pixel 2, the first time 
I didn't see the window but after that there is always a window with phone number and buttons.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ITelephony telephonyService;
        try {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                try {
                    Method m = tm.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");

                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);

                    if ((!isNumberInContactList(number))) {
                        telephonyService.endCall();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Ending the call from: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Accepting the call from: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I wonder if it is possible to completely hide the window and simply end the call without trace, except in the call log.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 2 remarks on your code: 
1- you should first check if your number is blocked or not in the beginning  (`isNumberInContactList`) to avoid unnecessary steps if it shouldn't be blocked 
2- in line

```
            telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
```

i don't think it will compile like that, because `ITelephony` can't be imported
but any way try to change that to :

```
Object telephonyInterface = methodGetITelephony.invoke(telephonyManager);
// Get the endCall method from ITelephony
Class telephonyInterfaceClass = 
           Class.forName(telephonyInterface.getClass().getName());
Method methodEndCall = 
        telephonyInterfaceClass.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");
// Invoke endCall()
methodEndCall.invoke(telephonyInterface);
```